# Sandwich estimators, robust standard errors

Tags: regression, prediction, robust-standard-error

I'm using R for modeling linear regression for prediction. Residuals do not met regression assumptions of homoscedasticity, therefore using library(lmtest) and library("sandwich") I've calculated new standard errors of coefficients. Now, I'm stuck with the question of what's next. How can I use this new weighted residuals in my regression for further prediction analysis?

Comment: Hi: This does a nice job providing the whole background and how it's applied. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich.pdf

Comment: The point of using robust standard errors is "only" to enable correct inference. The point estimates which you use for (at least for point) prediction are still obtained via OLS so that prediction analysis would be unaffacted (things can be different for prediction intervals).

Comment: Prediction under model mispecifications of the kind that robust SEs are supposed to deal with is... tricky. For somewhat negative view of the matter, see sec 3.1 of https://gking.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/robust_0.pdf